# I'm trying to UPDATE my table in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
If Me.dcBox & "" = "" Then
      CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE worklogData " & _
        " SET [Submitter] = '" & Me.subBox & "'" & _
        ", [Section] = '" & Me.secBox & "'" & _
        ", [Received By] = '" & Me.rbBox & "'" & _
        ", [Date Received] = """ & _
        ", [Serial Number] = '" & Me.snBox & "'" & _
        ", [Problem] = '" & Me.probBox & "'" & _
        ", [Computer Name] = '" & Me.cnBox & "'" & _
        ", [MAC] = '" & Me.macBox & "'" & _
        ", [Solution] = '" & Me.solBox & "'" & _
        ", [Completed By] = '" & Me.cbBox & "'" & _
        ", [Date Completed] = """ & _
        " WHERE [Order] = " & Me.orderBox.Tag & ""

    Else
        CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE worklogData " & _
            " SET [Submitter] = '" & Me.subBox & "'" & _
            ", [Section] = '" & Me.secBox & "'" & _
            ", [Received By] = '" & Me.rbBox & "'" & _
            ", [Date Received] = #" & Me.drBox & "#" & _
            ", [Serial Number] = '" & Me.snBox & "'" & _
            ", [Problem] = '" & Me.probBox & "'" & _
            ", [Computer Name] = '" & Me.cnBox & "'" & _
            ", [MAC] = '" & Me.macBox & "'" & _
            ", [Solution] = '" & Me.solBox & "'" & _
            ", [Completed By] = '" & Me.cbBox & "'" & _
            ", [Date Completed] = #" & Me.dcBox & "#" & _
            " WHERE [Order] = " & Me.orderBox.Tag & ""
    End If
```

I'm trying to UPDATE my table in Access VBA, but I found it causes Runtime Error: 3075 'Syntax error in date in query expression '#' when I try to UPDATE [Date Completed] field from what was blank previously.

And I've set Me.probBox as some text value which was previously blank, but [Problem] field doesn't be updated. What is surprising is there is no error coming out for this one.

Comment: Try this `", [Date Completed] = """"` instead of `", [Date Completed] = """`

Comment: Same for `", [Date Received] = """` Replace it with `", [Date Received] = """"`

Comment: In addition, your `If` statement does not look correct. If you are trying to check if Me.dcBox is populated, you can do something like this: `If Len(Trim(Me.dcBox)) Then`

Comment: Also, the 'logical and' is `and`, the 'bitwise and' is `&`.

Comment: @SiddharthRout actually as we look at ", [Date Completed] = """ & _, the fourth " is for making a new line 'cause the line becomes too long..? So there comes syntax error message when I apply your suggestion unfortunately...

Comment: My apologies. I was missing an extra `"`. It should have been `"""""`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE worklogData " & _
    " SET [Submitter] = '" & Me.subBox & "'" & _
    ", [Section] = '" & Me.secBox & "'" & _
    ", [Received By] = '" & Me.rbBox & "'" & _
    ", [Date Received] = """"" & _
    ", [Serial Number] = '" & Me.snBox & "'" & _
    ", [Problem] = '" & Me.probBox & "'" & _
    ", [Computer Name] = '" & Me.cnBox & "'" & _
    ", [MAC] = '" & Me.macBox & "'" & _
    ", [Solution] = '" & Me.solBox & "'" & _
    ", [Completed By] = '" & Me.cbBox & "'" & _
    ", [Date Completed] = """"" & _
    " WHERE [Order] = " & Me.orderBox.Tag & ""
```